# ExtJS 7.4(Modern Toolkit), Grid gridfilterbar plugin, filtered value not show on filterbar column when groupfield is using

Tags: extjs-grid, extjs7

I am using ExtJs 7.4(Modern toolkits) to create a grid with filterbar(with filter value) and groupfield(with group value), the filtered value not show on the filter bar. This is working perfectly in (Classic toolkit).

Here i attached my code in modern toolkit and classic toolkit.

modern toolkit: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3g3u 
classic toolkit: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3g3v

Comment: As I see the filter is working except for gender. And the default value set as filter for gender is not showing. Can you confirm that this is the problem? What you need is a default setting for some columns the filter bar?

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to make your code work as the following fiddle: 
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3g53

You might need to refer on [Ext JS Filterbar docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.4.0/modern/Ext.grid.plugin.filterbar.FilterBar.html).

As you can see their default filter value were put on grid column config.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).